# Purple and green screen when watching video on youtube?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, video, flash, youtube

Just installed ubuntu 12.04 lts onto my desktop. Everything works great but when i go to watch a video on youtube the video appears only in green and purple? Sound is coming through just fine and video is playing. The video is just hard to see. I am sure its something simple but does anyone have ideas? thanks.

Comment: Are you viewing the file using flash?  What graphics card do you have? Make and model if possible.

Comment: this is a known bug. Possible fixes, here: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/fix-pinkred-youtube-videos-bug-using.html

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your flashplayer and/or your video card drivers. If that's not an option, try to disable hardware accelleration in the flashplayer's settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the flash player that makes the bug. Try to reinstall adobe flash player or try Lightspark and see if that works.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend expanding this (click *edit* to edit) to include information and/or links about how to do these things (or at least about how to install and use Lightspark). You may also want to provide information about how to prefer Adobe Flash and Lightspark from interfering with one another if they're both installed, and/or how to *uninstall* Flash while using Lightspark.