# Anything that requires flash looks green and purple, and small

Tags: 12.04, flash, plugins, youtube, adobe

HI I am new to the Ubuntu community and Operating System (Ubuntu 12.04). After having recommended from my Compute Programming Teacher, I decided to install it. I'm satisfied with the operating system except for the Adobe Flash Plug-in. Anything that requires flash looks green and purple, but anything that has audio comes through just fine similar to this user's issue:
[Purple and green screen when watching video on youtube?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340981/purple-and-green-screen-when-watching-video-on-youtube)
No one seems to have provided any one with a sufficient answer so I have decided to ask again. I have tried many things including going to the Terminal and copying and pasting that install flash command. I've even decided to use LightSpark (although I'm not sure if I did it right). Nothing seems to work. I can watch you-tube videos using HTML5 however many other video players require Adobe Flash. Please list any and all techniques that could help me in this situation. The only thing I haven't tried so far is try to disable my hardware acceleration, which I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu 13.10 (newest version of the OS) and follow these instructions afterwards. It uses the Windows version of Flash and Silverlight (embedded in Linux Firefox). You not only have the app running like it should but you also have the latest release.

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [gnash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnash#Adobe_Flash_Player_End-User_License_Agreement)?

Otherwise (by firefox) get the official tar.gz and extraxt fatest mother into `~/mozilla/plugins`! If directory doesnt't exit create it! If no Firefox try Google, love-soldier!

**EDIT** Sorry it's  not `~/mozilla…` but `~/.mozilla/plugins` (if fireFox) andyou have to extract the `blablalib.so` by double-clicking the dowloaded tar.gz from official adorbe www. The dot before "mozilla" says it's hidden: Unhide it in your favourite file manager and rock on, love-soldier!

Comment: Hmm,I'm still new to Ubuntu operating system. So what do I do after I download the tar.gz from adobe. I double click it and then what? When I extract it am I not supposed to place it in the appropriate designation or something. I'm sorry for my incompetence the only way I know how to download and install is through the Software Centre. A step-by-step tutorial would really help me out.